# facebook add friend using ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I add friend from my facebook application using ajax call.
I have used the following, but it redirects to another page which contain confirmation box.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/friends/?id=FRIEND_ID&app_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL">
    ADD AS FRIEND
</a>
```

I want to send friend request as we are sending from anyone else profile page (Ajax call).

Answer (score 0):

May be this would help

```
<script> 
FB.ui({
    method: 'friends.add',
    id: fbid
}, function(param) {}); 
</script>​​
```